# JMeter - multiple user taking unique row from CSV file

Tags: csv, authentication, row, jmeter

I read many answers around regarding this topic, but I couldn't find the right one for me.

Requirements:

1. I have 2 threads/users
2. I have two entries in CSV Data Set Config for login.

The number of users will always be the same as the CSV rows.

My test looks like:

Thread Group

1. Homepage
2. Loop Controller
3. ---Login
4. ------CSV DataSetConfig
5. [another http call]

If I set number of threads 2 and Loop to 2 I get in Tree:

- Homepage1
- Login user1
- Login user2
- Homepage2
- Login user1
- Login user2

If I set number of threads to 2 and Loop to 1 I get:

- Homepage1
- Login user1
- Homepage2
- Login user1

If I set number of threads to 1 and Loop to 2 I get:

- Homepage1
- Login user1
- Login user2

I also tried to put the CSV Data set in the thread group before the login call. If I set 2 users to start the flow, always pick the first row from CSV.

What I need:

- Homepage1
- Login user1
- Homepage2
- Login user2
- Each user should continue it's flow

I could try to setup two Thread groups with specific user login, but it's not feasible because I want to increased the number of users and it's not maintainable.
As an overview, I have 4 flows and 200 users. After I solve this problem I will think about the user variability.

If anybody knows how to do it or can point me to the right info, please do so.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your loop controller, and put your csv file at the top of the testplan. Then set a synchronizing timer after the Login statement and set it to the max users.

Now all your users should login with a different value from csv value if there are enough, plus they will all continue at the same time waiting for all to login first.

Comment: That's the answer :) it seems I got stuck with that Loop controller and couldn't think without it. Just tried as you described and each user took it's own login credentials from CSV file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your csv like,

```
homepage1,user1
homepage2,user2
```

replace above values in your script for homepage and user login and use one line per thread (which is present in csv config)

[image]

so each thread will use whole line1 i.e. homepage1,user1 and will run as per your requirement.
That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific enough, Homepage call is outside CSV file. This CSV only holds the users and passwords. The flow sounds like: the user go to website homepage, do login (single session runtime) and than do something on the website. I cannot 'clone' the same user because of the session, that's why I need multiple users doing the same flow. Thanks anyway

Comment: The only reason I typed Homepage1 and Homepage 2 is to have an idea what user makes that call. But it's about the same URL

Comment: can you be more specific? I am confused with your needs

Comment: Sorry about that, Johan B. just answered below. Thanks anyway.